# Python - Problem involving multiplication between 'int' and 'type'

Tags: python, types

I am trying to make work a piece of code in Python, composed of four modules.

When running I get the following error in the module optimizer_Neuroevolution: "line 149, in evolve
    retain_length = int(len(graded)*self.retain)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'type'

The modules are as follow:

First module main_Neuroevolution:

```
    """Entry point to evolving the neural network. Start here."""
import logging
from optimizer_Neuroevolution_version_pure_neuroevolution import Optimizer
from tqdm import tqdm
from network_Neuroevolution_version_pure_neuroevolution import Network

# Setup logging.
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='log.txt'
)

def train_networks(networks):
    """Train each network.
    Args:
        networks (list): Current population of networks
        dataset (str): Dataset to use for training/evaluating
    """
    pbar = tqdm(total=len(networks))
    for network in networks:
        network.evaluate_neural_network()
        pbar.update(1)
    pbar.close()

def get_average_accuracy(networks):
    """Get the average accuracy for a group of networks.
    Args:
        networks (list): List of networks
    Returns:
        float: The average accuracy of a population of networks.
    """
    total_accuracy = 0
    for network in networks:
        total_accuracy += network.accuracy

    return total_accuracy / len(networks)

def generate(generations, population, dataset):
    """Generate a network with the genetic algorithm.
    Args:
        generations (int): Number of times to evole the population
        population (int): Number of networks in each generation
        nn_param_choices (dict): Parameter choices for networks
        dataset (str): Dataset to use for training/evaluating
    """
    optimizer = Optimizer(Network)
    networks = optimizer.create_population(population, dataset)

    # Evolve the generation.
    for i in range(generations):
        logging.info("***Doing generation %d of %d***" %
                     (i + 1, generations))

        # Train and get accuracy for networks.
        train_networks(networks)

        # Get the average accuracy for this generation.
        average_accuracy = get_average_accuracy(networks)

        # Print out the average accuracy each generation.
        logging.info("Generation average: %.2f%%" % (average_accuracy * 100))
        logging.info('-'*80)

        # Evolve, except on the last iteration.
        if i != generations - 1:
            # Do the evolution.
            networks = optimizer.evolve(networks)

    # Sort our final population.
    networks = sorted(networks, key=lambda x: x.accuracy, reverse=True)

    # Print out the top 5 networks.
    print_networks(networks[:5])

def print_networks(networks):
    """Print a list of networks.
    Args:
        networks (list): The population of networks
    """
    logging.info('-'*80)
    for network in networks:
        network.print_network()

def main():
    """Evolve a network."""
    generations = 30  # Number of times to evole the population.
    population = 1  # Number of networks in each generation.
    dataset = 'mnist'


    logging.info("***Evolving %d generations with population %d***" %
                 (generations, population))

    generate(generations, population, dataset) #generate(generations, population, nn_param_choices, dataset)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Second module optimiser_Neuroevolution:

```
    """
Class that holds a genetic algorithm for evolving a network.
Credit:
    A lot of those code was originally inspired by:
    http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/
"""
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
import random
from network_Neuroevolution_version_pure_neuroevolution import Network

class Optimizer():
    """Class that implements genetic algorithm for MLP optimization."""

    def __init__(self, retain=0.4, random_select=0.1, mutate_chance=0.5):
        """Create an optimizer.
        Args:
            nn_param_choices (dict): Possible network paremters
            retain (float): Percentage of population to retain after
                each generation
            random_select (float): Probability of a rejected network
                remaining in the population
            mutate_chance (float): Probability a network will be
                randomly mutated
        """
        self.mutate_chance = mutate_chance
        self.random_select = random_select
        self.retain = retain
        #self.network_characteristics = network_characteristics

    def create_population(self, count, dataset):
        """Create a population of random networks.
        Args:
            count (int): Number of networks to generate, aka the
                size of the population
        Returns:
            (list): Population of network objects
        """
        pop = []
        for _ in range(0, count):
            # Create a random network.
            network = Network()
            network.create_neural_network(dataset)


            # Add the network to our population.
            pop.append(network)

        return pop

    @staticmethod
    def fitness(network):
        """Return the accuracy, which is our fitness function."""
        return network.accuracy


    def grade(self, pop):
        """Find average fitness for a population.
        Args:
            pop (list): The population of networks
        Returns:
            (float): The average accuracy of the population
        """
        summed = reduce(add, (self.fitness(network) for network in pop))
        return summed / float((len(pop)))

    def breed(self, mother, father):
        """Make two children as parts of their parents.
        Args:
            mother (dict): Network parameters
            father (dict): Network parameters
        Returns:
            (list): Two network objects
        """
        children = []
        for _ in range(2):

            child = []

            # Loop through the parameters and pick params for the kid.
            characteristics = [first_characteristic, second_characteristic]
            for charac in characteristics:
                child[charac] = random.choice(
                    [mother.network[charac], father.network[charac]] #It is not going to work probably. Needs to precise the index of the child charac as well as the index of mother and father charac
                )

            network = Network()
            network.create_set(child)


            children.append(network)

        return children



    def evolve(self, pop):
        """Evolve a population of networks.
        Args:
            pop (list): A list of network parameters
        Returns:
            (list): The evolved population of networks
        """
        # Get scores for each network.
        graded = [(self.fitness(network), network) for network in pop]


        # Sort on the scores.
        graded = [x[1] for x in sorted(graded, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)]


        # Get the number we want to keep for the next gen.
        retain_length = int(len(graded)*self.retain)

        # The parents are every network we want to keep.
        parents = graded[:retain_length]

        # For those we aren't keeping, randomly keep some anyway.
        for individual in graded[retain_length:]:
            if self.random_select > random.random():
                parents.append(individual)

        # Now find out how many spots we have left to fill.
        parents_length = len(parents)
        desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
        children = []

        # Add children, which are bred from two remaining networks.
        while len(children) < desired_length:

            # Get a random mom and dad.
            male = random.randint(0, parents_length-1)
            female = random.randint(0, parents_length-1)

            # Assuming they aren't the same network...
            if male != female:
                male = parents[male]
                female = parents[female]

                # Breed them.
                babies = self.breed(male, female)

                # Add the children one at a time.
                for baby in babies:
                    # Don't grow larger than desired length.
                    if len(children) < desired_length:
                        children.append(baby)

        parents.extend(children)

        return parents
```

Third module Network_Neuroevolution:

```
    """Class that represents the network to be evolved."""
import random
import logging

from train_Neuroevolution_version_pure_neuroevolution import neural_network_evaluator

from train_Neuroevolution_version_pure_neuroevolution import get_cifar10
from train_Neuroevolution_version_pure_neuroevolution import get_mnist
import numpy as np


class Network():
    """Represent a network and let us operate on it.
    Currently only works for an MLP.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize our network."""
        self.accuracy = 0.
        self.network = []  # replaced (dic) by (list): represents MLP network parameters
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_lines = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_columns = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        #self.b1 = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_lines = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_columns = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS
        #self.b2 = 0 # MIGHT NEED TO REPLACE BY A VALUE WITH THE CORRECT NUMBER OF DIMENSIONS

    def create_neural_network(self, dataset):

        if dataset == 'cifar10':
            nb_classes, batch_size, input_shape, x_train, \
                x_test, y_train, y_test = get_cifar10()
        elif dataset == 'mnist':
            X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = get_mnist()

        n_x = X_train.shape[0]
        n_h = 64

        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x)
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_lines = self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer.shape[0]
        self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer_shape_columns = self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer.shape[1]
        #self.b1 = np.zeros((n_h, 1))
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer = np.random.randn(10, n_h)
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_lines = self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer.shape[0]
        self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer_shape_columns = self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer.shape[1]
        #self.b2 = np.zeros((10, 1))

        self.network = [[self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer], [self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer]]



    def evaluate_neural_network(self):

        self.accuracy = neural_network_evaluator(self.input_layer_to_hidden_layer, self.hidden_layer_to_output_layer)



    def create_set(self, network):
        """Set network properties.
        Args:
            network (dict): The network parameters
        """
        self.network = network


    def print_network(self):
        """Print out a network."""
        logging.info(self.network)
        logging.info("Network accuracy: %.2f%%" % (self.accuracy * 100))
```

Fourth module train_Neuroevolution:

```
    """
Utility used by the Network class to actually train.
Based on:
    https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py
"""
from keras.datasets import mnist, cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import numpy as np


# Helper: Early stopping.
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(patience=5)

def get_cifar10():
    """Retrieve the CIFAR dataset and process the data."""
    # Set defaults.
    nb_classes = 10
    batch_size = 64
    input_shape = (3072,)

    # Get the data.
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.reshape(50000, 3072)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 3072)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255

    # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

    return (nb_classes, batch_size, input_shape, x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

def get_mnist():


    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
    X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]


    X = X / 255

    digits = 10
    examples = y.shape[0]

    y = y.reshape(1, examples)

    Y_new = np.eye(digits)[y.astype('int32')]
    Y_new = Y_new.T.reshape(digits, examples)

    m = 60000
    m_test = X.shape[0] - m

    X_train, X_test = X[:m].T, X[m:].T
    Y_train, Y_test = Y_new[:,:m], Y_new[:,m:]

    return (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test)


def sigmoid(z):
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return s


def compute_multiclass_loss(Y, Y_hat):

    L_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(Y_hat)))
    m = Y.shape[1]
    L = -(1/m) * L_sum

    return L



def neural_network_evaluator(input_layer_to_hidden_layer, hidden_layer_to_output_layer):

    X_train = get_mnist()[0]
    Y_train = get_mnist()[2]


    Z1 = np.matmul(input_layer_to_hidden_layer,X_train) #+ b1 #Put X_train and not X
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.matmul(hidden_layer_to_output_layer,A1) #+ b2
    A2 = np.exp(Z2) / np.sum(np.exp(Z2), axis=0)

    cost = compute_multiclass_loss(Y_train, A2)

    return cost
```

Sorry for all the comments in the code.
This is a modified version of an original piece of code. I tried to find an answer but could not find something related. I guess it is due to some compatibility problems, I might have use classes in a wrong way. Do you have any idea why this is causing this problem?

Comment: That is a whole lot of code for a single line error. Check the types of `len(graded)` and `self.retain` to see if they are what you think they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function,

```
def generate(generations, population, dataset):
```

you instantiate Optimizer and pass it Network

```
optimizer = Optimizer(Network)
```

your class Optimizer is

```
class Optimizer():
    """Class that implements genetic algorithm for MLP optimization."""

    def __init__(self, retain=0.4, random_select=0.1, mutate_chance=0.5):
        """Create an optimizer.
```

So when you instantiate it, you're getting retain=Network, random_select=01, mutate_chance=0.5.

Later on, you try to

```
retain_length = int(len(graded)*self.retain)
```

So you try to do len(graded), an integer * Network (it's not a float).

BTW thank you for posting all your code and the traceback. 99% of the these questions don't have code/traceback and I have no idea wtf they're even asking.

Comment: Yes I tried to give as much details as possible, as my first experience posting a question was quite catastrophic!